# Xamarin CarouselView using List<ContentView>

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, carousel

I am trying to fill a `CarouselView` with a `List` of `ContentView`.  Can anyone help?

I've tried for 2 days this is as close as I get but I just get a blank page.  In my tests the new Content views actually have data, but I stripped that out for simplicity sake.  They do display their content if I set them as content manually but not with the `CarouselView`.

CodeBehind

```
List<ContentView> viewList = new List<ContentView>();
viewList.Add(new ContentView()); //Data Entry for Book information
viewList.Add(new ContentView()); //Data Entry for Widget information
viewList.Add(new ContentView()); //Data Entry for Quijibo information

var myCarousel = new CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.CarouselViewControl();
myCarousel.ItemsSource = viewList;
myCarousel.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ContentView));
myCarousel.Position = 1; //default
myCarousel.Orientation = CarouselViewOrientation.Horizontal;

myContentPresenter.Content = myCarousel;
```

XAML

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" />
```

2nd Attempt, thought I'd go back to example that works from a google search [YouTube Video by Houssem Dellai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQSJWN6accU) then modify it as little as possible.  Still get a blank screen.

Code Behind

```
var NameList = new List<ContentView>();
NameList.Add(new ContentViewBook());
NameList.Add(new ContentViewWidget());
NameList.Add(new ContentViewQuijibo());

//var NameList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };   This works with XAML Label

mainCarouselView.ItemsSource = NameList;
```

XAML

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="mainCarouselView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--<Label Text="{Binding .}" />  This works with List<String>-->
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

This is the code that works when done manually.  I used `MR.Gestures` to catch the swipe and change the Content.  Which works, but does not seem to catch the swipes all that well.

Code Behind

```
myContentView.Content = new ContentViewQuijibo();
```

XAML

```
<ContentView x:Name="myContentView" />
```

Comment: I dont know a thing about xamarin. However [this page](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) talks about `Init`. Have you done that?

Comment: I haven't as I do have it working without "Init", if I use a label and text.  As far as I can tell that page is not showing how to use different ContentViews but different data using the same data template. I have that working no problem.  Each of my ContentViews use different datasets and layouts so that pages hasn't helped me much.